# How to handle file uploads in featherjs?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, feathersjs

I am trying to to handle a multipart form file upload in feathersjs using multer, I have tried to copy the file contained in `req.picture` to the server using `blobService` and `blobStorage` and get a url to the file and then replace the `req.picture` with the returned url. After that `req` should be handed over to `feathers-mongoose` to persist in the database. Going through official docs https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/file-uploading.html I have come up with following but I am getting nowhere with it.

Items Service | Also Only if I change  `blobService({ Model: blobStorage})` to `createService(options)` then other methods like get works , if not it does not.

```
    // Initializes the `items` service on path `/items`
const createService = require('feathers-mongoose');
const createModel = require('../../models/items.model');
const hooks = require('./items.hooks');
const filters = require('./items.filters');
const multer = require('multer');
const multipartMiddleware = multer();
const blobService = require("feathers-blob");
const fs = require("fs-blob-store");
const blobStorage = fs("./public/items/pictures");

module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'items',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/items',
    multipartMiddleware.single('picture'),
    function(req, res, next){
      req.feathers.file = req.picture;
      req.picture = 'url to the file';
      next();
    },
    blobService({ Model: blobStorage}));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('items');

  service.hooks(hooks);

  if (service.filter) {
    service.filter(filters);
  }
};
```

Items service hooks

```
const { authenticate } = require('feathers-authentication').hooks;
const fileUpload = require('../../hooks/file-upload').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [fileUpload],
    update: [fileUpload],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
```

Hook for file upload (file-upload.js)

```
const dauria = require('dauria');
module.exports = {
  hooks: function(hook) {
    if (!hook.data.uri && hook.params.file){
      const file = hook.params.file;
      const uri = dauria.getBase64DataURI(file.buffer, file.mimetype);
      hook.data = {uri: uri};
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response I get on postman

```
    {
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {},
    "errors": {}
}
```

Comment: Try debug mode (https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/debugging.html) to see more details of the errors you are getting.

Comment: I ended up removing blob storage and blob service altogether and just configured multer to save the file, but still I don't have any idea how to do this with feathers-blob

Comment: @v1shva do you have any example of this. I'm having issues too